# Excel Conditional Formatting Rule

Tags: excel

I am trying to put a border in my table separated by due dates. For some reason excel is putting the border 2 rows above where it needs to be. I looked up other formulas on Stackoverflow.com but I still come up with the same issue.

[I am using the formula $C3<>$C4 with the Format as a Bottom Border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK7Nm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula needs to point to the top row of the `Applies To` Range:

```
=$C1<>$C2
```

**OR**

Your `Applies To` Range needs to start at row 3:

```
=$B3:$C306
```

But the first row of the `Applies To` needs to be the **SAME** as the row in the first reference.

Comment: Perfect! That's all I needed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: When the question is 15 minutes old you will be able to mark this as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer, please do so then, as it will remove it from the unanswered queue. @go.surf13